# Regex: How to search in reverse, obtaining all characters up to a specific character?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have `wordsandnumbers!morestuff!morelettersandnumbers`, I want to get everything after the last `!` (meaning there may be more than 2 `!`). How can I do this using regex?

Comment: Try this: [`[^!]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/LqKpoe/1/)

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which language, Python or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can *anchor* your regular expression match to the end of your string with `$`, and then take all the consecutive non-exclamation marks you can up to that point:

[`[^!]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/LqKpoe/1)